# How to syle a Gtk::ComboBox

Tags: css, combobox, gtkmm

I've been trying for two months now to find a way how to style a ComboBox, but unfortunately nothing works... The only thing I was able to do was to style the content of the ComboBox (the cell renderer), but not the ComboBox itself.
Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

gtk_style_context_add_class ( gtk_widget_get_style_context (combobox) ,"button or any style you want");

Comment: It would be nice to show some context for how this would fit in, as well as some explanation of what is happening.

Comment: I know how to add a CSS file to the ComboBox (I've done that to other controls, like buttons, treeviews, etc, etc), but it doesn't style the ComboBox, whatever I write in it...